# ListView SelectedItem not highlighted when set in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, highlighting, selecteditem

I have a `ListView` with a `ItemSource` data binding and a `SelectedItem` data binding.

The `ListView` is populated with a new `ItemSource` every time I press the Next or Previous button.

The `SelectedItem` is updated accordingly, the items in the `ItemSource` have the `Selected` state, so it can be remembered when the user navigates back and forth.

While debugging, everything seems to work perfectly. The VM updates the controls as expected, and I can also see that the `ListView` has the correct selected value when I navigate with the next and previous buttons.

The problem is, that regardless of the fact that the ListView has a correct `SelectedItem`, the `ListView` does not visualize the `SelectedItem` as highlighted.

XAML:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="_matchingTvShowsFromOnlineDatabaseListView" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableMatchingTvShows}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding AcceptedMatchingTvShow, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Behaviour in ViewModel responsible for repopulating the `ItemSource` and the `SelectedItem`:

```
private void UpdateForCurrentVisibleTvShow()
{
    var selectedTvShow = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];

    // Update the available matches
    var availableMatchingTvShows = new ObservableCollection<IWebApiTvShow>();
    if (AvailableTvShowMatches[selectedTvShow] != null)
    {
        foreach (var webApiTvShow in AvailableTvShowMatches[selectedTvShow])
        {
            availableMatchingTvShows.Add(webApiTvShow);
        }
    }
    AvailableMatchingTvShows = availableMatchingTvShows;

    // Update the selected item
    AcceptedMatchingTvShow = availableMatchingTvShows.FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);

    // Update the progress text
    CurrentTvShowInfoText = string.Format(
        "TV Show: {0} ({1} of {2} TV Shows)",
        FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow],
        CurrentTvShow + 1,
        FoundTvShows.Count);

    // Update the AcceptedMatchingTvShow selection in the listview
    OnPropertyChanged("AcceptedMatchingTvShow");
}
```

The implementation of `AcceptedMatchingTvShow`:

```
public IWebApiTvShow AcceptedMatchingTvShow
{
    get
    {
        IWebApiTvShow acceptedTvShow = null;
        if (FoundTvShows.Count > 0)
        {
            var tvShowName = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];
            acceptedTvShow = AvailableTvShowMatches[tvShowName].FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);
        }
        return acceptedTvShow;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var tvShowName = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];
            var currentlyAcceptedTvShow =
                AvailableTvShowMatches[tvShowName].FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);
            if (currentlyAcceptedTvShow != null)
            {
                currentlyAcceptedTvShow.Accepted = false;
            }
            value.Accepted = true;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. Just to be clear, the ListView has the correct items, and the SelectedItem is set with the correct item.

Comment: Try in the code behind `this.UpdateLayout();` You can call this on the `SelectionChanged event`. You don't change anything in a `VM` this way so it's only `View` that is affected. HTH

Comment: Where do you set `AcceptedMatchingTvShow`?

Comment: @Sinatr I updated the question with that part of the code as well. It does not have a backing field which needs to be updated, it just needs to read the property again and evaluate which TV Show was the `Selected` one

Comment: your  OnPropertyChanged(); shouldn't take the name of the property that changed?

Comment: you don't have any style removing the selected item hightlight?

Comment: @sexta13, that `OnPropertyChanged` method probably has the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) declared on the input parameter, so it can access the name automatically without passing it.

Comment: @bas, where do you set the `SelectedItem` property from code? Please show that.

Comment: @Sheridan, I did not set it from the VM. I thought that the control would check for a `SelectedItem` because of the binding. I updated the code in the question, now it does set the `SelectedItem` (bound to `AcceptedMatchingTvShow`). Still no luck.

Comment: You should set it to an actual item from the data bound collection, *not* a copy of them. Try something like this instead: `AcceptedMatchingTvShow = AvailableMatchingTvShows.FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);`

Comment: @Sheridan that is the exact same line I pasted above. Also, not sure how all this works behind the scenes, but I implemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on the `IWebApiTvShow` just to be on the safe side. Anyway, I am 100% sure that I set an object as `SelectedItem` from the `ItemSource` list

Comment: @Sheridan ahh, now I see, the capital `A` :). It was a reference to the same list, I changed it to what you proposed to make sure that it works all the same. Still seems hard to get the selected item visualized correctly. It must have something to do with the order of updates that are generated between View and ViewModel... So close.. yet so far away... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found 'a solution' to the problem after a lot of debugging and digging. I would REALLY like to understand if this is how WPF meant the control to behave, or if this is a bug in the `ListView`s data binding part. If anyone could tell me that, I am very very curious to the correct answer (and maybe I solved this problem in the wrong way, and somebody could explain me how I should've done this).

Anyway, the problem seems to be resolved when I create a **copy** of the object:

```
    public IWebApiTvShow AcceptedMatchingTvShow
    {
        get
        {
            IWebApiTvShow acceptedTvShow = null;
            if (FoundTvShows.Count > CurrentTvShow)
            {
                var tvShowName = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];
                acceptedTvShow = AvailableTvShowMatches[tvShowName].FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);
            }

            if (acceptedTvShow != null)
            {
                // I MUST create a new instance of the original object for the ListView to update the selected item (why??)
                return new WebApiTvShow(acceptedTvShow);
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var tvShowName = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];
                var availableTvShowMatch = AvailableTvShowMatches[tvShowName];
                var currentlyAcceptedTvShow = availableTvShowMatch.FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);
                if (currentlyAcceptedTvShow != null)
                {
                    currentlyAcceptedTvShow.Accepted = false;
                }
                value.Accepted = true;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Note the call to the copy constructor :

`return new WebApiTvShow(acceptedTvShow);`

It works, but seems really ridiculous and smells like a bug in `ListView` to me. Is it?

I tried to explain the same problem in a simpler example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919112/listview-remember-selecteditem-not-working-as-i-expected-a-bug-in-wpfs-listvi), if anybody can confirm the bug or can explain me how this should've been implemented I would greatly appreciate the insights.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but I had been jumping through hoops to solve this Problem in a similar setup. Setting the SelectedItem in a ListView using a bound Property in the Viewmodel or similar using a bound SelectedIndex just would not work. Until I tried to do it async:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       BoundSelectedIndex = index;
   });
```

Seems to work - more advanced contributors may answer why...

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old post but what worked is overriding the Equals and GetHashCode on your SelectedItem object so the listview can compare the SelectedItem  with the bound collection