# ListView 'remember' SelectedItem not working as I expected, a bug in WPFs ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, selecteditem

In a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887599/listview-selecteditem-not-highlighted-when-set-in-viewmodel?noredirect=1#comment40517549_25887599) question I described a problem where I couldn't figure out how to remember and set the `SelectedItem` on a `ListView`. The problem is, when I set the `SelectedItem` from my ViewModel, the ListView does not show the `SelectedItem` as highlighted.

The question remained unanswered, so I tried to reproduce the problem in a small example. To my big surprise, I just learned that the problem is solved when I create a **copy** of the original selected item (which I stored in my ViewModel), and set that as selected item. If I set the exact same object which was already set, then the listview will NOT show the selected item.

### A short intro:

I have a `ListView` which shows items which are data bound to `ItemSource`. The `SelectedValue` is also data bound to a property on the ViewModel. I have two buttons, previous and next, to navigate through different object sets, each object set contains a different `ObersevableCollection` which is bound to the `ListView`s `ItemSource`.

The idea is that the selection made in a `ListView` is stored, so that when the same object set is shown again, the item which was selected previously is selected again.

Below the (ugly testing) code that brought me to the point where I am now:

Note; the for me surprising part is covered in method `ShowList1CommandOnExecute()`. I added comments which explain what seems weird to me, while it seems to be the only way to get it working properly.

### MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _index;

    private Person _selectedPerson1;
    private Person _selectedPerson2;
    private Person _selectedPerson3;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _list1;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _list2;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _list3;

    public RelayCommand ShowList1Command { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand ShowList2Command { get; set; }

    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            switch (_index)
            {
                case 0:
                    return _selectedPerson1;
                case 1:
                    return _selectedPerson2;
                case 2:
                    return _selectedPerson3;
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                switch (_index)
                {
                    case 0:
                        _selectedPerson1 = value;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        _selectedPerson2 = value;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        _selectedPerson3 = value;
                        break;
                }
            }
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ShowList1Command = new RelayCommand(ShowList1CommandOnExecute, ShowList1CommandOnCanExecute);
        ShowList2Command = new RelayCommand(ShowList2CommandOnExecute, ShowList2CommandOnCanExecute);
        _list1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        _list1.Add(new Person { Name = "Bas" });
        _list1.Add(new Person { Name = "Anke" });
        _list1.Add(new Person { Name = "Suus" });
        _list2 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        _list2.Add(new Person { Name = "Freek" });
        _list2.Add(new Person { Name = "Ina" });
        _list2.Add(new Person { Name = "Liam" });
        _list3 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        _list3.Add(new Person { Name = "aap" });
        _list3.Add(new Person { Name = "noot" });
        _list3.Add(new Person { Name = "mies" });

        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    }

    private void ShowList1CommandOnExecute()
    {
        if (_index < 3)
        {
            _index++;
        }
        else
        {
            _index = 0;
        }

        switch (_index)
        {
            case 0:
                Persons = _list1;
                if (_selectedPerson1 != null)
                {
                    // This is what surprised me, this DOES work. Why do I need a copy of an object??
                    SelectedPerson = new Person(_selectedPerson1.Name);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                Persons = _list2;
                // This did work, which is why I tried the copied object (see case 0)
                SelectedPerson = new Person {Name = "freek"};
                break;
            case 2:
                Persons = _list3;
                if (_selectedPerson3 != null)
                {
                    // This will NEVER result in the selected item to be visualized as selected
                    // However, when you will check while debugging, the ListView DOES contain the correct selected item
                    SelectedPerson = _selectedPerson3;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private bool ShowList1CommandOnCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ShowList2CommandOnExecute()
    {
        switch (_index)
        {
            case 0:
                SelectedPerson = new Person {Name = "bas"};
                break;
            case 1:
                SelectedPerson = new Person {Name = "Freek"};
                break;
            case 2:
                SelectedPerson = new Person{Name = "mieS"};
                break;
        }
    }

    private bool ShowList2CommandOnCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### The very simple entity class `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Person;

        if (other != null)
        {
            return Name.ToLowerInvariant().Equals(other.Name.ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

### A very simple UI, two test buttons and a `ListView`:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Height="90" Width="90" Command="{Binding ShowList1Command}">Show List1</Button>
        <Button Height="90" Width="90" Command="{Binding ShowList2Command}">Show List2</Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <ListView 
        x:Name="_matchingTvShowsFromOnlineDatabaseListView" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Again, the question:

Why do I need to create a copy of the previously `SelectedItem` and set that copy again as selected item in order for the ListView to visualize (and highlight) the SelectedItem in the ListView?

Comment: In the selected item can you try adding UpdateSourceTrigger property to PropertyChanged and check ??

Comment: @adityaswami89 Hi, just tried it, same result. It still only works when I start to create copies of the originally selected item.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated your issue, but have yet to pinpoint exactly what the problem is. What I can tell
you is that while it appears that nothing is selected, the value of SelectedItem on the ListView is actually correct. I can come to no other conclusion than this is unexpected behaviour of the ListView/ListBox in WPF. So it appears that you are indeed correct - it is a bug.

Now, in regards to solving your issue, here is what I would suggest:

The View (I removed the RelayCommand for simplicity):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Height="90" Width="90" Click="Button_Click">Toggle List</Button>

        <ListView
            DataContext="{Binding Persons}"
        x:Name="_matchingTvShowsFromOnlineDatabaseListView" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _index;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set
        {
            _index = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private SelectionCollection<Person> _list1;
    private SelectionCollection<Person> _list2;
    private SelectionCollection<Person> _list3;

    private SelectionCollection<Person> _persons;
    public SelectionCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _list1 = new SelectionCollection<Person>();
        _list1.Add(new Person { Name = "Bas" });
        _list1.Add(new Person { Name = "Anke" });
        _list1.Add(new Person { Name = "Suus" });
        _list2 = new SelectionCollection<Person>();
        _list2.Add(new Person { Name = "Freek" });
        _list2.Add(new Person { Name = "Ina" });
        _list2.Add(new Person { Name = "Liam" });
        _list3 = new SelectionCollection<Person>();
        _list3.Add(new Person { Name = "aap" });
        _list3.Add(new Person { Name = "noot" });
        _list3.Add(new Person { Name = "mies" });

        Persons = new SelectionCollection<Person>();

    }

    public void ShowList1CommandOnExecute()
    {
        if (Index < 2)
        {
            Index++;
        }
        else
        {
            Index = 0;
        }

        switch (Index)
        {
            case 0:
                Persons = _list1;
                break;
            case 1:
                Persons = _list2;
                break;
            case 2:
                Persons = _list3;
                break;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And finally, a newly introduced collection that is also able to track selection:

```
public class SelectionCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _selectedItem;
    public T SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this can also be accomplished by using CollectionViews, but personally, I prefer not having these in my ViewModel layer.

Also note that the _index field was converted to a property only to allow me to bind to it, as I got confused by it ranging between 0-3, instead of 0-2 (also fixed above).

Comment: I will give this a try! Thanks.. PS: the _index solution is horrible, it only served the purpose to reproduce the problem. Thanks for bringing `SelectionCollection` to my attention!

Comment: Please try explaining the OP's problem first before giving a work-around. I've just copied the OP's code and tried it myself and felt  that it's really an interesting issue. Answering like this will make others ignore the question and there won't be any explanation about the issue.

Comment: @KingKing: I did the best I could with the time I had available. I have had a bit more time to look into it, and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but I had been jumping through hoops to solve this Problem in a similar setup.
Setting the SelectedItem in a ListView using a bound Property in the Viewmodel or similar using a bound SelectedIndex just would not work.
Until I tried to do it async:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    BoundSelectedIndex = index;
                });
```

Seems to work - more advanced contributors may answer why...